# passing variable of a Database Connection $conn=pg_connect(...) to library routines

Tags: php

I have PHP scrips that connect to a database and call prepared functions from a `library.php` file.

Script.php:

```
   ...
   require("library.php");

   $conn=pg_connect(.....)
   $_SESSION['conn']=$conn;

   $ret_json=get_this_or_that($json_query);
   .....
```

The file library.php contains multiple functions that query the database:

library.php:

```
   ....
   function get_this_or_that ($json_query) {
      ...
      $conn           =$_SESSION["conn"];
      #########
      $SQL="SELECT ....";
      $result_set=pg_query($conn,$SQL);
      #more code
    
   
      return $json;
   }
   ....
   function (...
```

Apparently passing the variable `$conn` using a SESSION variable or even a global variable is not secure.

I do not want to pass it in the function calling as in

```
get_this_or_that($conn,$json_query);
```

What other options do I have?

Thank you

Need a way to pass the object `$conn` to other PHP routines

Comment: You could declare it as a private property of a class and initialise it in the constructor. Then all your class methods would have access to it as `$this->conn`. That would involve rewriting your functions to be class methods.

Comment: Create a PHP file with purely connection code, nothing else. Now include this file in any other file where you want to do database-related stuff. Right now it seems that you are mixing both in each file.

Comment: Security is not relevant here. A session variable won't work because sessions are for storing data to be serialised between requests, and a connection can't be serialised (= turned into a string and back). A global variable is not *insecure*, it's just hard to work with as your program gets more complex - you'll thank yourself later for structuring things differently.

Comment: Database connections are closed when the script finishes, that's why it's pointless to store them for later. It doesn't have anything to do with security, it simply does not work. You can pass absolutely any variable as function argument, you seem to be trying to build a complicated workaround because you've somehow assumed that you can only pass strings or texts.

Comment: `I do not want to pass it in the function calling`...why not? That's the obvious thing to do. If you follow Tangentially's suggestion and refactor your code into a class-based structure, you could reduce the surface area of this by only passing it into the constructor of each class which needs it. This would be the first stop on the way to implementing the dependency injection pattern, which a lot of people recommend these days.